# Weird behavior of simple tables in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I am a beginner in Python. The dynamic programming solution to the [coin change problem](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change) requires an initialized table that basically could, for example, look like this:

```
[
[1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0]
]
```

Which table I specified this way:

```
table=[[1]+[0]*3]*3
```

Now, if I write

```
table[1][2]=1
for x in table: print x
```

I get a print of:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 2, 0]
```

And I have no damn clue why the whole column gets changed instead of the specified number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the code you didn't show.  Presumably, you initialised your list like

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 0]
table = [a, a, a]
```

or

```
table = [[1, 0, 0, 0]] * 3
```

or something equivalent, which leads to a list containing three times the same list object.  If you modify this single object, it changes everywhere it is referenced, because it is only a single object.

If you need further details, show us the code creating the table.

A correct way of initializing `table` is

```
table = [[1, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(3)]
```

or simply

```
table = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Welcome to SO.  Your new question is already answered in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
t = [
    [1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
]

t[1][2]=1
for x in t: print x
```